# three tables relations SQL select

Tags: sql, relational

I'm learning SQL, so help is greatly appreciated.

I have three tables: `league`, `player` and `team`

- `league` and `player` is many to many (as a player can be in more than one league)
- `team` and `player` is many to many (as a player can be on a team in multiple leagues)
- `league` and `team` is one to many.

I have the following table ids:

```
league.id  ----. league_has_player (league_id, player_id) .------   player.id
team.id    ----. team_has_player (team_id, player_id)     .-----  player.id
league     ----. team.id (team.league_id)
```

I want to get all the players in the league who are not on a team in the league.

Here's my broken attempt.

```
Select *
from player p,
    join team t on t.league_id = l.id 
    join league l on league.id = 2
where p.id = league_has_player.player_id and
     not in (select team_has_player.player_id from team_has_player)
```

Comment: Your query and explanation does not make sense.  What is `team_has_player`?  Please explain what all the tables mean.

Comment: your table structure is not clear. what does league_has_player and team_has_player represent in the database - are these functions?

Comment: what database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying more for something like this. As a couple comments have pointed out, your table schema isn't clear. But this is the impression I get from your attempt.

```
DECALRE @leagueId...

SELECT *
FROM player
WHERE player.id IN (SELECT player_id
                    FROM league_has_player
                    WHERE league_id = @leagueId) AND
      player.id NOT IN (SELECT player_id
                        FROM team_has_player
                            INNER JOIN team ON team.Id = team_has_player.team_id
                        WHERE team.league_id = @leagueId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the players registered for the league, where they don't belong to a team in the league.

```
SELECT p.*, lp.league_id
FROM player p
JOIN league_has_player lp ON lp.player_id = p.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                  FROM team_has_player tp
                  JOIN team t ON t.id = tp.team_id
                  AND tp.player_id = p.player_id
                  AND t.league_id = lp.league_id)
```